# Need information in rows into columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Currently I have a view which gets user, date, session id, activity and hostname.

User logins to a system and a session id is created, same session id gets updated for the logoff as well.

View data:

| user | date | session_id | activity | hostname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 2023-02-07T11:02 | 45 | Login | XYZ |
| X | 2023-02-07T11:06 | 45 | Logout | XYZ |
| Y | 2023-02-07T10:02 | 67 | Login | ABC |
| Y | 2023-02-07T10:32 | 67 | Logout | ABC |
| X | 2023-02-06T11:02 | 48 | Login | XYZ |
| X | 2023-02-06T11:06 | 48 | Logout | XYZ |

I want the data to come out  as below,

| user | Hostname | login | logout |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | XYZ | 2023-02-07T11:02 | 2023-02-07T11:06 |
| Y | ABC | 2023-02-07T10:02 | 2023-02-07T10:32 |
| X | XYZ | 2023-02-06T11:02 | 2023-02-06T11:06 |

I have written a query using pivot

```sql
select * from ( select user, date, session_id, activity, hostname from view)
pivot ( max(date) for activity in ('login','logoff')) view
```

I am getting the results as expected but I don't want session_id to come up in the results and also the column name for login & logoff is as 'login' and 'logoff', how can I rename them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want certaing columns displayed then do not `SELECT` them (naming the ones you do want to display rather than using `SELECT *`) and if you do not want the default column aliases then explicitly provide your own aliases:

```sql
SELECT username,
       hostname,
       login,
       logoff
FROM   (
  SELECT username,
         date_column,
         session_id,
         activity,
         hostname
  FROM   view_name
)
PIVOT (
   MAX(date_column) FOR activity IN (
     'login' AS login,
     'logout' AS logoff
  )
);
```

or, if you do not want to group by the session id:

```sql
SELECT username,
       hostname,
       login,
       logoff
FROM   (
  SELECT username,
         date_column,
         activity,
         hostname
  FROM   view_name
)
PIVOT (
   MAX(date_column) FOR activity IN (
     'login' AS login,
     'logout' AS logoff
  )
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mlnldUbp)

Comment: Thanks , this worked with grouping session_id.

Comment: Hi MT0,  In the above view view_name, I now have extra two columns which hold hostname_logon and hostname_logoff. Every row has one of this column as null. Using the above query, I want the output with username, hostname, hostname_logon , hostname_logoff,login & logoff. I need the group by with username, date_column,activity, session_id & hostname.   How can i get the columns which are not in the select query of group by

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (cuser, datum, session_id, activity, hostname) as
  2    (select 'x', to_date('07.02.2023 11:02', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 45, 'Login' , 'xyz' from dual union all
  3     select 'x', to_date('07.02.2023 11:06', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 45, 'Logout', 'xyz' from dual union all
  4     select 'y', to_date('07.02.2023 10:02', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 67, 'Login' , 'abc' from dual union all
  5     select 'y', to_date('07.02.2023 10:32', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 67, 'Logout', 'abc' from dual union all
  6     select 'x', to_date('06.02.2023 11:02', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 48, 'Login' , 'xyz' from dual union all
  7     select 'x', to_date('06.02.2023 11:06', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 48, 'Logout', 'xyz' from dual
  8    )
```

Query:

```
  9  select cuser, hostname,
 10    max(case when activity = 'Login'  then datum end) login,
 11    max(case when activity = 'Logout' then datum end) logout
 12  from test
 13  group by cuser, hostname, session_id
 14  order by cuser, login;

C HOS LOGIN            LOGOUT
- --- ---------------- ----------------
x xyz 06.02.2023 11:02 06.02.2023 11:06
x xyz 07.02.2023 11:02 07.02.2023 11:06
y abc 07.02.2023 10:02 07.02.2023 10:32

SQL>
```